# Trouble with emscripten setup

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, emscripten

I'm trying to setup emscripten. So, I followed [this](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Tutorial) instructions.

```
To use Emscripten and complete this tutorial, you need a few things:

    The Emscripten code, from github (git clone git://github.com/kripken/emscripten.git. The master branch is fine, it is guaranteed to always be stable. We merge to master only after all tests pass.)
    LLVM with Clang. Version 3.2 is the officially supported version, others may not work. There are official clang binaries that include LLVM for some platforms, if yours is not there then you should get the LLVM and Clang sources and build them.
    Node.js (0.8 or above)
    Python 2.7.3
```

I checked versions by this lines:

`node --version` -> `v0.10.15`

`python --version` -> `Python 2.7.3`

I had no LLVM and Clang installed. So, I install them by this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kxstudio-team/builds
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install llvm clang
```

then, I'm checking their versions:

`llvm-config --version` -> `3.2`

`clang --version` ->

```
Ubuntu clang version 3.2-1~exp9ubuntu1~precise1 (tags/RELEASE_32/final) (based on LLVM 3.2)
Target: i386-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Next, I'm downloading emscripten by this command:

`git clone git://github.com/kripken/emscripten.git ~/emscripten` (as follows in tutorial)

Entering emscripten directory: `cd ~/emscripten`

Also, I followed this:

```
Before continuing, it's a good idea to make sure the requirements work. Try

clang tests/hello_world.cpp
./a.out

(Add the path to clang if it isn't installed systemwide.) That uses Clang and LLVM to compile a "hello world" app and run it. The second command there should print "hello, world!". Then, test Node.js with

node tests/hello_world.js

which should also print out "hello, world!". (As before, add the path to node if it isn't installed systemwide.)
```

Outputs are `hello, world!` in both commands.

Next, first launching emcc:

`./emcc` (as follows in tutorial)

Outputs:

```
==============================================================================
Welcome to Emscripten!

This is the first time any of the Emscripten tools has been run.

A settings file has been copied to ~/.emscripten, at absolute path: /home/<my-user-name>/.emscripten

It contains our best guesses for the important paths, which are:

  LLVM_ROOT       = /usr/bin
  PYTHON          = /usr/bin/python2
  NODE_JS         = /usr/bin/node
  EMSCRIPTEN_ROOT = /home/<my-user-name>/emscripten

Please edit the file if any of those are incorrect.

This command will now exit. When you are done editing those paths, re-run it.
==============================================================================
```

Checking those paths to make sure they are correct:

`/usr/bin/python2 --version` -> `Python 2.7.3`

`/usr/bin/node --version` -> `v0.10.15`

`/usr/bin/llvm-config --version` -> `3.2`

It looks ok. Now I'm gonna try to compile examples from tutorial:

Building example 1:

```
./emcc tests/hello_world.cpp
```

Outputs: '' (nothing)
Running example 1:

```
node a.out.js
```

Outputs: `hello, world!`

Building example 2 (Generating HTML):

```
./emcc tests/hello_world_sdl.cpp -o hello.html
```

Outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./emcc", line 1428, in <module>
    libfile = shared.Cache.get(name, create)
  File "/home/<my-user-name>/emscripten/tools/cache.py", line 37, in get
    shutil.copyfile(creator(), cachename)
  File "./emcc", line 1234, in create_libc
    return build_libc('libc.bc', libc_files)
  File "./emcc", line 1204, in build_libc
    shared.Building.link(o_s, in_temp(lib_filename))
  File "/home/<my-user-name>/emscripten/tools/shared.py", line 891, in link
    if Building.is_bitcode(f):
  File "/home/<my-user-name>/emscripten/tools/shared.py", line 1272, in is_bitcode
    b = open(filename, 'r').read(4)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmphG0_UZ/dlmalloc.c.o'
```

No 'hello.html' created!
**What I'm doing wrong?**

Additional information:

```
uname -a

Linux <name-of-my-system> 3.2.0-29-generic-pae #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:25:43 UTC 2012 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux
```

I searched this on Google but their solutions are not helping me. (more different errors and more pain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks very similar to the issue reported here:
https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/1432

Comment: Indeed, this is similar to mine. I followed man's suggestion and downloaded a source code of LLVM, CLANG and compiled them by myself. And that's worked. Looks like libraries which are on repositories are broken or not compatible to my system. Compilation time - ~3 hours on my system (Athlon 2.2 Ghz, 3 Gb RAM).